# How to reverse of paragraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a paragraph, any paragraph. I want to print that in reverse order.

eg. i/p -> "This is java script". Then output should be "script Java is This".

**How do I do this without using split, reverse or join function, just by traversing?**

Comment: I smell an assignment. At least show us what you've tried.

Comment: You have to show what you have tried

Comment: `str.split(/\s/).reverse().join(' ')`

Comment: the question was incomplete? please answer now.

Answer (score 1):

```
var yourstring="This is java script";
var reversed= yourstring.split(/\s/).reverse().join(' ');

console.log(reversed);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "This is java script";
function reverse(s){
    return s.split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
}
alert(reverse(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
str = "This is a simple sentence";
str = str.split(" ").reverse().join(' ');
alert(str);
```